# mariadb won't let me access from "remote"

Tags: mariadb

I have one Linux computer(CentOS7.4) as server, one windows computer. I have setup the mariadb server. On windows, I use mysql-workbench as client.

[image]

However, I can access the server via 'tcp/ip over ssh', but when I connect using 'tcp/ip' I get 10060 error.
[image]

By the way, I can `ping 192.168.1.11`, it seems the network is ok. Therefore, what's wrong with my setting?

### three things to check

1. the user and host:

[image]

2. and 3. the settings file in `/etc/my.cnf`:
   [image]
3. server.cnf

[image]

5. mysqld
   [image]
6. bind-adress and skip-networking
   [image]

Comment: Please check all you config files, see the include command at the end of /etc/my.cnf. The settings you're looking for are probably in /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf.

Comment: @dbdemon I have checked the config files, they are just empty, no configuration set in those files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four things to check:

1. Check that the DB user allows for connecting from the remote client. A user has a both a 'user' and a 'host' component. `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;` will show your users including their hosts, i.e. the clients they allow. You can use the wildcard '%' to allow connecting from any client, or a specific IP address or hostname if you prefer that.
2. Make sure that the `skip-networking` variable is not enabled in the configuration files.
3. Make sure `bind-address` is either not enabled or pointing to a specific IP address you want to allow in the configuration files.

Once you have updated the configuration files, restart MariaDB.

Check the MariaDB documentation on [configuring for remote client access](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/) for details.

4. Make sure the firewall on CentOS isn't blocking access:

   `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=mysql`

   `sudo systemctl restart firewalld`

Comment: I have update the information of your "three things to check", please have a look where the problem might be.

Comment: If you want to ensure that people are alerted to the fact that you've responded to a comment, put @ in front or their handle - i.e. for me it's @Vérace - p.s. welcome to the forum! Just a small thought on the problem - do you have rules on the server disabling non-ssh connections?

Comment: @Vérace I don't know how to check if I have disabled the non-ssh connections, but ping works.

Comment: Use putty and try to login not using ssh?

Comment: @buzhidao I think `skip-networking` was only used in config files of older MariaDB versions, so you may or may not find that in the config files, but I suspect `bind-address` is still there.

Comment: @dbdemon see my new update, it is empty.

Comment: @Vérace should I try login using telnet? telnet is not considered secure by centos, should I install it so that tcp/ip connection to the database to work?

Comment: Yes, and see what happens!

Comment: @Vérace after I install and configure the telnet service, I can remote login to the server using telnet, but still can't directly connect to the sql database.

Comment: Hmm... have you tried connecting with the mysql client?

Comment: @buzhidao Did you telnet to port 3306? If not, try that. Could the Windows machine firewall be blocking traffic on that port? Just a wild guess ...

Comment: @dbdemon I don't think the windows firewall is blocking the traffic, because I can use tcp/ip log in other mysql-server on port 3306. The telnet default port is 23, so I didn't try 3306.

Comment: @buzhidao If you log in to CentoOS using SSH, what are the outputs from the following two commands: `mysqld --verbose --help | grep bind-address` and `mysqld --verbose --help | grep skip-networking` ?

Comment: @dbdemon I don't have the command `mysqld`

Comment: @buzhidao Strange, maybe it's not in your PATH. What about `/usr/sbin/mysqld`? If so, use that instead of `mysqld`.

Comment: @dbdemon Still, there is no mysqld command. I am using mariadb5.5 and centos7.4, `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.56-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
`

Comment: @buzhidao `/usr/sbin/mysqld` is the correct default path for MariaDB 5.5 on CentOS 7.4 - I've checked. You can also run the command `ps -ef | grep mysql` which should show any running mysql* commands including mysqld.

Comment: @dbdemon please see my edit, still no `mysqld`

Comment: @buzhidao It says `/usr/libexec/mysqld`. Please use that in place of just `mysqld` for the commands I suggested earlier.

Comment: @dbdemon I have run the commands, please see my update.

Comment: Hi @buzhidao , I think I've found the issue and the solution after testing on a VM - see the fourth item in my updated answer above.

Comment: @dbdemon Thanks, your method works!  Does `--zone=public` option all people outside the local network connect my database? I mean, if someone know my server's public ip address, can they connect to it if they also know a user name and password. The best option for my is only connect via ip start with `192.168.*`, i.e. my working network.

Comment: @buzhidao Excellent, glad to hear it works now. Yes, I think the `firewall-cmd` opens up the port to the world. Your MariaDB users however are created such that they can only log in from a limited set of local IP addresses (127.0.0.1, localhost, ::1, 192.168.*). I don't know if it's possible to set a rule in the firewall so that it will only allow certain IP address ranges. Sounds like a good question for serverfault.com or similar.

Comment: @dbdemon Thanks, I will try to search the answer somewhere.

Comment: @dbdemon I've asked the question on server fault: https://serverfault.com/q/915442/472900